# How to access the Shiny dashboard hosted on a Linux EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny

After I installed R and Shiny package on a Linux instance, I was able to run a Shiny example using `runExample('01_hello', host = 'the.same.ip.as.the.instance', port = 443, launch.browser = F)`. The output in the console is

> Listening on http://*the.same.ip.as.the.instance*:443

The problem is when I try to see the dashboard by putting this address (http://*the.same.ip.as.the.instance*:443) in Chrome, I got this error:

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> *the.same.ip.as.the.instance* took too long to respond.

Since I can access the instance using Putty from the same computer and network, I don't think it's security group issue.

What would be the correct way to access the dashboard hosted on an EC2 on AWS?

Comment: Are u accessing through public DNS/IP address? The information in your question is limited.

Comment: I put in http:/10.xx.xx.xxx:443, which is the same IP as the instance.

Comment: 10.xxx.xx is a private IP range and it cannot be accessed outside the VPC

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: It is a broad question. Do you have a public IP associated to your instance. It depends on whether you created the instance in a private or a public subnet

Comment: It’s in a private subnet.